# Binding tab controls with mahapps and prism - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, mahapps.metro

I am building a WPF application with `mahapps`, `prism`[modularity]. I have below `HomeWindow.xaml` code.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Project.Views.HomeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Views"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" 
        <!--The above code is for automatically binding of viewmodel into view-->
        Height="700" Width="1200" Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>                            
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

I have below structure in my `HomeViewModel.cs` under `ViewModels` directory.

```
public class HomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _tabCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> TabCollection { get { return _tabCollection; } set { SetProperty(ref _tabCollection, value); } }
    //Prism way of getting and setting data
}

public class Item
{
    private string Name;
    private string Content;

    public Item(string name, string content)
    {
        Name = name;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

below is how I add data into `TabCollection` property through `HomeWindow.xaml.cs`.

```
private HomeViewModel _model=new HomeViewModel();
public HomeWindow(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _model.UserViewModel = model;
    LoadHomeData(_model.UserViewModel.EmpRole);
    DataContext = this;
}

private void LoadHomeData(string Role)
{
    if (string.Equals(Role, "Admin"))
    {
        _model.TabCollection= new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item("Test1", "1"),
            new Item("Test2", "2"),
            new Item("Test3", "3")
        };
    }
}
```

Now matter what, the tabs will not get displayed. Its a blank empty window. I have followed the example in the **[`issue here`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/172)** and have went through few similar posts having same kind of approach. But none of them helped. Is this because of `prism` way of `databinding` or is there anything else am missing here? Hope to find some help on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not connected to MahApps or Prism but to how WPF works in general. In your case `Name` and `Content` are private fields and should be **public properties**

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
```

private or field is not a valid binding source. You can find more as to what is a valid binding source under [Binding Sources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx) but in your case, as far as CLR object goes:

> **You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.** The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

Another problem is that `DataContext` is set wrong. At the moment is set to `HomeWindow` and I think it should be set to instance of `HomeViewModel` which holds `TabCollection` property

```
DataContext = _model;
```

Comment: Good catch buddy.. But still no luck.. I made it `public` as you said...

Comment: Did you also made it a property by adding `{ get; set; }`?

Comment: Yes, I did.. I doubt `prism` creating some prob here.. not sure though..

Comment: check my edit, there is also a problem in `DataContext`

Comment: ah.. yea.. that was the issue.. Is it ok if I revert back to my old settings now, regarding `private-public` properties or it should stay as is??

Comment: No, it must stay as public property. As I explained when it's private or a field it won't bind.

Comment: Alright buddy.. Thank you so much for your time and kind advice.. :) Happy coding.. :)